# how to create columns in a list and assign values in array in a column of a table into them?

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a table like this below and the last column has array values

```
| job_id| timestamp                   |item_values   |
|:----  |:---------------------------:|:------------:|
| job1  | 2022-02-15T23:10:00.000+0000|[0.2,3.4,13.2]|       
| Three | 2022-02-15T23:20:00.000+0000|[0.1,2.9,11.2]|
| job2  | 2022-02-15T23:30:00.000+0000|[1.2,3.1,16.0]|
| job3  | 2022-02-15T23:40:00.000+0000|[0.4,0.4,16.2]|       
| job4  | 2022-02-15T23:50:00.000+0000|[0.7,8.4,11.2]|
| job5  | 2022-02-15T24:00:00.000+0000|[0.3,1.5,19.1]|  
| job6  | 2022-02-15T24:10:00.000+0000|[0.7,7.4,13.2]|
```

and I have a list of the item_names here like below

```
[item1,item2,item3]
```

and I want output like this

```
 | job_id| timestamp                  |item1|item2|item3|
|:----  |:---------------------------:|:----|-----|-----|
| job1  | 2022-02-15T23:10:00.000+0000|0.2  | 3.4 | 13.2|    
| Three | 2022-02-15T23:20:00.000+0000|0.1  | 2.9 | 11.2|
| job2  | 2022-02-15T23:30:00.000+0000|1.2  | 3.1 | 16.0|
| job3  | 2022-02-15T23:40:00.000+0000|0.4  | 0.4 | 16.2|  
| job4  | 2022-02-15T23:50:00.000+0000|0.7  | 8.4 | 11.2|
| job5  | 2022-02-15T24:00:00.000+0000|0.3  | 1.5 | 19.1|
| job6  | 2022-02-15T24:10:00.000+0000|0.7  | 7.4 | 13.2|
```

How can I do this using pyspark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I reproduce same thing in my environment. I got this output.**

Define the list of item names and use this code to create new columns for each item name using enumerate.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, explode

# Create sample data

d123 = [("job1", "2022-02-15T23:10:00.000+0000", [0.2,3.4,13.2]),
("Three", "2022-02-15T23:20:00.000+0000", [0.1,2.9,11.2]),
("job2", "2022-02-15T23:30:00.000+0000", [1.2,3.1,16.0]),
("job3", "2022-02-15T23:40:00.000+0000", [0.4,0.4,16.2]),
("job4", "2022-02-15T23:50:00.000+0000", [0.7,8.4,11.2]),
("job5", "2022-02-15T24:00:00.000+0000", [0.3,1.5,19.1]),
("job6", "2022-02-15T24:10:00.000+0000", [0.7,7.4,13.2])]

df = spark.createDataFrame(d123, ["job_id", "timestamp", "item_values"])

#list of item_names
item_nam12 = ["item1", "item2", "item3"]

for i, item_n12 in  enumerate(item_nam12):
    df = df.withColumn(item_n12, col("item_values")[i])
    
df = df.drop("item_values")
df.show()
```

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: hi @MMV, can you provide error trace or error image.

Comment: Hi Sorry it worked! but I need to do something slightly different. I just posted a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75829554/how-can-i-assign-values-in-an-array-to-a-table-with-new-columns-named-from-a-lis

Answer (score 0):

Use `getItem()` to extract values by index from array column

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

for i in range(3):
  df = df.withColumn("item" + str(i+1), F.col("item_values").getItem(i))
```