# How can I assign values in an array to a table with new columns named from a list

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table like this and I have a column named input_values here which the values in the arrays go to the ml models. the first value of the each array goes to model1 and second to the model2 ..and so on.

```
| job_id | timestamp                          | input_values      |
|:----   |:----------                         | -----------       |                     
| job1   | 2023-03-01T19:12:00.000+0000       | [0.12,0.34,0.23]  |
| job2   | 2023-03-01T19:13:00.000+0000       | [0.23,0.55,0.12]  |
| job3   | 2023-03-01T19:14:00.000+0000       | [0.23,0.12,0.32]  |
```

and I have another table like this
columns has the ml output result

```
    | model_A| model_B | model_C |
    |:---- |:------:   | -----:  |
    | 1    | 1         |  1      |
    | 1    | 1         |  0      |
    | 0    | 1         |  1      |
```

what I want to do is I want is I want to add the input value columns to the output table.
I will have created a list of input names

```
input_names = [input_A,input_B,input_C]
```

and this is the table I finally need.

```
| model_A| model_B | model_C |input_A|input_B|input_C|
|:---- |:------:   | -----:  |----   |----   |----   |
| 1    | 1         |1        |0.12 |0.34  |0.23  |
| 1    | 1         | 0       |0.23 |0.55   |0.12 |
| 0    | 1         | 1       |0.23| 0.12  |0.32   |
```

how can I do this using pyspark?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are methods I can think

**Method-1:**-
Below are the assumption, i assuming the that the length of column **input_values** is same across data.Also you just want convert the array in the column to columns with values given below.

```
input_names = [input_A,input_B,input_C]
```

I hope below code would work for you.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as func

leng = len(df1.first()['input_values'])

df1.select([func.col('job_id'),func.col('timestamp'),*(func.col('input_values')[i].alias(input_names[i]) for i in range(leng))]).show()
```

the above code should give you the output as below

```
+------+--------------------+-------+-------+-------+
|job_id|           timestamp|input_A|input_B|input_C|
+------+--------------------+-------+-------+-------+
|  job1|2023-03-01T19:12:...|   0.12|   0.34|   0.23|
|  job2|2023-03-01T19:12:...|   0.23|   0.55|   0.12|
|  job3|2023-03-01T19:12:...|   0.23|   0.12|   0.32|
+------+--------------------+-------+-------+-------+
```

hope above one is the expected from your side.

**Method-2** : This is more rigid than the method 1 as we are trying to avoid loops as it may cause issues while using it for large number dataframe.

In order for this to work the column ***input_values*** should be array.

```
df1.dtypes

[('job_id', 'string'),
 ('timestamp', 'string'),
 ('input_values', 'array<double>')]
```

Then instead of using loops we will be calling them directly by referring to their position .

```
df2=df1.select("job_id","timestamp",func.struct(df1.input_values[0].alias("input_A"),df1.input_values[1].alias("input_B"),df1.input_values[2].alias("input_C")).alias("input"))
```

Now the if call printschema .the output will look like below.

```
df2.printSchema()

root
 |-- job_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- input: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- input_A: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- input_B: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- input_C: double (nullable = true)
```

Now all you have to do is call select again.

```
df2.select("job_id","timestamp",'input.*').show()
```

Hopefully method 2 should run a little better than the method 1.

Comment: Hi @Avind thanks for your answer! is there a way to keep other columns as well when doing it??

Comment: Also I'm doing this with a large table.. and it takes about one and a half hours to be completed. How can I do the performance tuning?

Answer (score 0):

**I reproduce same thing in my environment. I got this output.**

Create two data frame and join the two data frame on the row index, select the columns you want to include in the output table.

**Sample Code:**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id   
# create sample dataframe for the input table
d1 = [(0.12, 0.34, 0.23), (0.23, 0.55, 0.12), (0.23, 0.12, 0.32)]
d1_cols = ['input_A', 'input_B', 'input_C']

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(d1, d1_cols)
input_df1 = df1.withColumn('id', monotonically_increasing_id())
 

# create Another dataframe.
op_data = [(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1)]
op_cols = ['model_A', 'model_B', 'model_C']
op_df = spark.createDataFrame(op_data, op_cols)
op_df = op_df.withColumn('id', monotonically_increasing_id())
  

# join the two tables on the row index.
joined_df1 = op_df.join(input_df1, 'id', 'inner')

 
# select the columns what you want to include in the output table using `select`.
col_select = ['model_A', 'model_B', 'model_C', 'input_A', 'input_B', 'input_C']
result_df = joined_df1.select(col_select)
   

# show the final table
result_df.show()
```

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I don't have id column in the second table with ml output values.. so I can't use join function.. so i don't think it works for my case :(

Comment: hi @MMV, apply `monotonically_increasing_id()` to both the input and output tables, and add the "id" column to each table. it will work..